# Given $n$ (string length) and $k$ (number of characters to be used to form the string). Find number of string with $0$ to $k$ repeating substrings

Tags: probability

**Question:** Given $n$ (string length) and $k$ (number of characters to be used to form the string). Find number of string with $0$ to $k$ repeating substrings.

For example:
$k=2$ and $n=3$. $S(1)$-number of possible strings that have substring with no repeating characters (e.g. $101,010$). $S(2)$-number of possible strings having substring with two repeating characters (e.g. $001,100,110,011$). $S(3)$ number of possible strings having substring with three repeating characters (e.g. $000,111$).

I am not able to approach this problem. Please help me figure out how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

For the  case $k=2$ we  consider $S_q$ the  number of strings  with at
most $q$ repeating characters. We introduce

$$F(z) = z + z^2 + \cdots + z^q =
z(1+\cdots+z^{q-1}) = z \frac{1-z^q}{1-z}$$

and obtain the generating function ($z$ for  a one digit and $w$ for a
zero digit)

$$G(z, w) = (1 + F(w)) 
\left(\sum_{q\ge 0} F(z)^q F(w)^q\right) (1 + F(z))
= (1+F(w))\frac{1}{1-F(z)F(w)} (1+F(z)).$$

As we are only interested in the count we may put $z=w$ to obtain

$$H(z) = \frac{(1+F(z))^2}{1-F(z)^2}
= \frac{(1-z^{q+1})^2}{(1-z)^2-z^2(1-z^q)^2}
\\ = \frac{1-2z^{q+1}+z^{2q+2}}{1-2z+2z^{q+2}-z^{2q+2}}.$$

For  a   closed  form   that  does  not   require  the   resources  of
differentiation we extract

$$T_p = [z^p] \frac{1}{1-2z+2z^{q+2}-z^{2q+2}}
= [z^p] \sum_{r_1\ge 0} z^{r_1} (2 - 2z^{q+1} + z^{2q+1})^{r_1}
\\ = \sum_{r_1=0}^p [z^{p-r_1}] (2 - 2z^{q+1} + z^{2q+1})^{r_1}
\\ = \sum_{r_1=0}^p [z^{p-r_1}] 
\sum_{r_2=0}^{r_1} {r_1\choose r_2} 2^{r_1-r_2} 
z^{(q+1)r_2} (z^{q}-2)^{r_2}
\\ = \sum_{r_1=0}^p
\sum_{r_2=0}^{r_1} {r_1\choose r_2} 2^{r_1-r_2} 
[z^{p-r_1-(q+1)r_2}] (z^{q}-2)^{r_2}
\\ = \sum_{r_2=0}^p
\sum_{r_1=r_2}^p {r_1\choose r_2} 2^{r_1-r_2} 
[z^{p-r_1-(q+1)r_2}] (z^{q}-2)^{r_2}
.$$

Here we must have $p-r_1-(q+1)r_2 = q r_3$ where $0\le r_3 \le \lfloor
p/q \rfloor$ and hence $r_1 = p - (q+1) r_2 - q r_3 \ge 0$ so that
$r_2 \le (p - q r_3) / (q+1)$ which yields

$$\sum_{r_3=0}^{\lfloor p/q \rfloor}
\sum_{r_2=0}^{\lfloor (p - q r_3) / (q+1) \rfloor}
{p - (q+1) r_2 - q r_3 \choose r_2} 2^{p - (q+2) r_2 - q r_3}
[z^{q r_3 }] (z^{q}-2)^{r_2}
\\ = \sum_{r_3=0}^{\lfloor p/q \rfloor}
\sum_{r_2=0}^{\lfloor (p - q r_3) / (q+1) \rfloor}
{p - (q+1) r_2 - q r_3 \choose r_2} {r_2\choose r_3}
(-1)^{r_2-r_3}  2^{p - (q+1) (r_2 + r_3)}.$$

We then get the closed form

$$T_p - 2 T_{p-q-1} + T_{p-2q-2}$$

with negative  indices representing empty sums  and contributing zero.
For example we obtain for  strings of length $40$ classified according
to  the maximum  value $q$  of  repeated substrings  the sequence  for
$q=30..40$

$$1099511622144, 1099511625216, 1099511626624, 1099511627264, 
\\ 1099511627552, 1099511627680, 1099511627736, 1099511627760, 
\\ 1099511627770, 1099511627774, 1099511627776.$$

where $2^{40} = 1099511627776.$ This  example is included here because
it  documents  the  limits  of coefficient  extraction  using  Maple's
**coeftayl** command  and is obviously  impossible to attack  by total
enumeration.

An important sanity check here is that we must have $[z^p] H(z) = 2^p$
when  $q\ge p$  (this is  the case  where the  limit on  the repeating
substrings   is   at  least   the   length   of  the   strings   being
queried). Indeed we find for these $p$

$$[z^p] \frac{1-2z^{q+1}+z^{2q+2}}{1-2z+2z^{q+2}-z^{2q+2}}
= [z^p] \frac{1}{1-2z+2z^{q+2}-z^{2q+2}}
\\ = \sum_{r_1=0}^p [z^{p-r_1}] 
\sum_{r_2=0}^{r_1} {r_1\choose r_2} 2^{r_1-r_2} 
z^{(q+1)r_2} (z^{q}-2)^{r_2}
= \sum_{r_1=0}^p [z^{p-r_1}] 2^{r_1} = 2^p.$$

This  was  the Maple  code  that  was  used  to work  with  these
generating  functions and  verify the  data by  enumeration as  far as
possible.

```
RL :=
proc(n, q)
option remember;
local ind, d, pos, cur, run, runs, res, allq;
    res := 0;

    for ind from 2^n to 2*2^n-1 do
        d := convert(ind, base, 2);

        cur := -1; pos := 1;
        run := []; runs := [];


        while pos <= n do
            if d[pos] <> cur then
                if nops(run) > 0 then
                    runs :=
                    [op(runs), [run[1], nops(run)]];
                fi;

                cur := d[pos];
                run := [cur];
            else
                run := [op(run), cur];
            fi;

            pos := pos + 1;
        od;

        runs := [op(runs), [run[1], nops(run)]];

        allq := select(r -> r[2] <= q, runs);

        if nops(allq) = nops(runs) then
            res := res + 1;
        fi;
    od;

    res;
end;

X := (n, q) ->
coeftayl((1-2*z^(q+1)+z^(2*q+2))/(1-2*z+2*z^(q+2)-z^(2*q+2)),
         z=0, n);

T := (p, q) ->
add(add(binomial(p-(q+1)*r2-q*r3, r2)*binomial(r2, r3)
        *(-1)^(r2-r3)*2^(p-(q+1)*(r2+r3)),
        r2 = 0 .. floor((p-q*r3)/(q+1))), r3=0..floor(p/q));

S := (n, q) -> T(n, q)-2*T(n-q-1, q)+T(n-2*q-2, q);
```

**Addendum.** An alternative means of computing $T_p$ is to use
a recurrence. We obtain

$$[z^p] H(z) (1-2z+2z^{q+2}-z^{2q+2})
= [[p=0]] - 2 [[p=q+1]] + [[p=2q+2]]$$

or

$$T_p = 2 T_{p-1} - 2 T_{p-q-2} + T_{p-2q-2}
+ [[p=0]] - 2 [[p=q+1]] + [[p=2q+2]]$$

where negative indices produce a zero contribution.

**Remark.** Use $S_q-S_{q-1}$ for the case where at least one instance of a string of $q$ repeating characters is required.

Comment: Can you explain me what is happening here?..This is a probability question,so how was this equation derived

Comment: The probability is $[z^n] H(z)/2^n.$  You might want to augment the problem statement if you are not looking for an exact probability but rather seek to describe the distribution i.e. $S_q-S_{q-1}$ where $1\le q\le n.$ We get for $n=10$ the distribution $2, 176, 370, 254, 126, 56, 24, 10, 4, 2.$